# Why does boot2docker, and port forwarding to my docker instances, periodically hang?

Tags: virtualbox, osx-yosemite, boot2docker

I have run the following command to forward sinatra and redis ports to my docker instance running in virtualbox on OSX:

```
ports=( 4567 6379 )
for port in "${ports[@]}"
do
echo "Forwarding $port"
VBoxManage modifyvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "tcpport$port,tcp,,$port,,$port"
done
```

However, periodically (like every 60 seconds) requests to either of these docker instances over my machine's public IP, originating from my machine, will hang for 40-60 seconds. However, my docker instance is healthy and I can connect directly via 192.168.59.103.

Thus, why would a connection such as:

```
redis-cli -h 192.168.1.1 PING
```

Periodically hang, but

```
redis-cli -h 192.168.59.103 PING
```

Always work? Is there some kind of bug in VirtualBox or boot2docker?

Moreover, during the periods where these requests hang, I have noticed that calls to

```
boot2docker ip
```

and

```
boot2docker ssh
```

Themselves both hang. I am running boot2docker 1.6.2 and VirtualBox 4.3.28 on OSX 10.10.3.

Additional debugging reveals that inter-instance connectivity is now impaired as well. I have linked two containers, and periodically HTTP requests between them will hang. I went so far as to run `telnet container_name 4567`, then I typed

```
GET /
```

Which, of course, is the most basic way to test a webserver. From inside of container_name, I ran `curl http://localhost:4567/`. The telnet request hung, but the `curl http://localhost:4567/` returned immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the main reasons we added the extra localhost only interface (`192.168.59.103`) - the virtual box bat port forwarding is woeful and very unreliable.

Comment: OK got it -- thank you for this info! It sounds like this is probably a (known?) bug of VirtualBox then.